# How to draw a chart on Widget using SwiftUI with the help of Charts framework or any other framework alternative?

Tags: charts, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I am new to SwiftUI and I want to draw a chart on Widget with the help of the SwiftUICharts framework (https://github.com/AfrazCodes/SwiftUICharts) or any other framework alternative, please can someone help me?

```
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    //Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    VStack{

        let iPhone = Legend(color: .blue, label: "iPhone 10")
        
        let points: [DataPoint] = [
            .init(value: 2, label: "2", legend: iPhone),
            .init(value: 4, label: "4", legend: iPhone),
            .init(value: 7, label: "7", legend: iPhone),
            .init(value: 1, label: "1", legend: iPhone)
        ]

        LineChartView(dataPoints: points)
        
    }
}
```

this is the basic demo code I did.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might useful to someone. While there is SwiftCharts which is available for iOS 16. You can watch this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn34Kz0g5HE) video for iOS 15 and below